# Let $I=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^2dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

Suppose $f$ is a continuous real-valued function. Let $I=\int_0^1 f(x)x^2 \, dx$.Then it is necessarily true that $I$ equals :
(A)$\frac{f(1)}{3}-\frac{f(0)}{3}$,
(B)$\frac{f(c)}{3}$ for some $c \in [0,1]$,
(C)$f(1/3)-f(0)$,
(D)$f(c)$ for some $c \in [0,1]$.

I was thinking about it but do not know how to tackle it.Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: If you use the function $f(x)=1$ you eliminate $A,C,D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem for integration to deduce that (B) is true.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have got it.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function takes all values between minimum and maximum. It is evident that:

$\frac{f_{min}}{3} \le I \le \frac{f_{max}}{3}$

i.e. :

$f_{min} \le 3 I \le f_{max}$

so there is $c$ so that $3I=f(c)$, i.e. $I=\frac{f(c)}{3}$